# Download does not work when more than one interactive report on one page at oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I'm running ords in standalone mode it's working fine, but when I try to run ords with apache tomcat i'm facing the issue below.

I am working on oracle apex 5 and I have created multiple interactive report on one page but then download functionality is not working, i found that while downloading it generate url like following:

```
http://ipaddress:8081/ords/f?p=108:16:sessionid:IR[R12484134506260525]_CSV::::
```

and when only one interactive report on single page it generate url like following (which is working):

```
http://ipaddress:8081/ords/f?p=108:17:sessionid:CSV::::
```

how can i manage to download report with multiple interactive report on single page?

Comment: Define "not working"...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to download each Interactive Report (IR) separately; IE: if you would want to have links to download all three reports, you would need to have three links built, with the appropriate IR IDs:

```
http://ipaddress:8081/ords/f?p=108:16:sessionid:IR[R12484134506260525]_CSV::::
http://ipaddress:8081/ords/f?p=108:16:sessionid:IR[R12484134508888888]_CSV::::
http://ipaddress:8081/ords/f?p=108:16:sessionid:IR[R12484134509999999]_CSV::::
```