# Oracle Apex: Cannot download interactive report when more than one report lives on one page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hi I'm using Oracle Apex version 20.1. I've read about someone with a similar problem in a blog post here: [Download does not work when more than one interactive report on one page at oracle apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371073/download-does-not-work-when-more-than-one-interactive-report-on-one-page-at-orac). I can download the requested IR through the actions menu when it's the only report on the page. But when I use the actions menu to try and download the same report on my other page (which has one form and multiple reports) it just refreshes the page and sets my form fields back to default. I also notice that the download url changes from

`https://transengine-dev.dev.actumprocessing.com:8443/ords/f?p=500:501:7870471954917:CSV::::`

to

`https://transengine-dev.dev.actumprocessing.com:8443/ords/f?p=500:81:7870471954917:IR%5BR398147140862231567%5D_CSV::::&cs=33Et3cGqxfXDNwO6R4YmJHZ8jy6Bdk6Ef255gHvw_pfDuFLxMBudNruiscd3nSN2liXFZDoesmdRYzXTCfHga9Q`

Any suggestions?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that both report regions have the same static id - that sometimes causes unwanted behaviour. Can you check that ?

Comment: And in my case after some patch or something, they generally stopped downloading, even the report name is still the same and default. I have an old ORDS maybe it's the fault, but it's strange that it stopped working so suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it on apex.oracle.com (which currently runs Apex 21.2.0) and it seems that it works OK.

Two interactive reports on the same page (querying Scott's `EMP`) table; I ran the page and downloaded (via the Actions menu) both of them one after another - no problem. Therefore, perhaps you should upgrade (can't test on your version, I don't have it).

[image]